# Trait function alias on magic __callStatic function

Tags: php, alias, traits, magic-methods

I've got a Queryable trait which implements the __callStatic method to make a new instance of a Builder and run the called function on it (if it exists). It returns the Builder in order to chain queries (much like Eloquent).

Now I'm trying to implement an interface that needs the find() function but I've got the find() function declared in phpDoc on the Quaryable trait (`@method static static find(mixed $primaryKeyValue)`) and it creates a conflict:

> Declaration of 'Queryable::find(primaryKeyValue: mixed)' must be compatible with 'StorageInterface->find(primaryKeyValue: mixed)', cannot make interface method

In order to fix the conflict, I'm trying to use something like the trait alias (`use Queryable { Queryable::find as queryFind; }`) to resolve it, but then I get hit with the

> Compile Error: An alias was defined for app\Framework\Traits\Queryable::find but this method does not exist

I can't seem to find a solution for this, could some guru help me out? :) (pretty sure it has to do with somekind of exists check on the class that fails because it is a magic method but I wouldn't know how to fix that either..)

```
<?php

namespace app\Framework\Traits;

use app\Framework\Database\Builder;
use app\Framework\Database\Paginator;

/**
 * @method static int count()
 * @method static static|array<static> first(int $amount = 1)
 * @method static static|array<static> last(int $amount = 1)
 * @method static string getQuery()
 * @method static string getRawQuery()
 * @method static string getPrimaryKey()
 * @method static static find(mixed $primaryKeyValue)
 * @method static array<static> all()
 * @method static array<static> get()
 * @method static Paginator paginate()
 * @method static Builder table(string $tableName)
 * @method static Builder primaryKey(string $primaryKey)
 * @method static Builder perPage(int $perPageAmount)
 * @method static Builder where(string $column, mixed $operatorOrValue = null, mixed $value = null)
 * @method static Builder whereIn(string $column, array $search)
 * @method static Builder whereNotNull(string $column)
 * @method static Builder select(...$columns)
 * @method static Builder with(string $relation, \Closure $closure)
 * @method static Builder orderBy(string $column, string $direction = 'desc')
 * @method static Builder limit(int $amount)
 * @method static Builder offset(int $amount)
 */
trait Queryable
{
    public static function __callStatic(string $name, array $arguments)
    {
        $functions = get_class_methods(Builder::class);
        if (in_array($name, $functions)) {
            $builder = new Builder(static::class);
            return $builder->$name(...$arguments);
        }

        $selfFunctions = get_class_methods($calledClass = static::class);
        if (!in_array($name, $selfFunctions)) {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException("Static method '{$name}' does not exist on {$calledClass}.");
        }

        return static::$name(...$arguments);
    }

}


class BaseModel extends \stdClass implements QueryableInterface, StorableInterface
{
    use Queryable {
        Queryable::find as queryFind;
    }

    public function find(mixed $primaryKeyValue): static
    {
        return self::queryFind($primaryKeyValue);
    }
}

<?php

namespace app\StorageMethods;

interface StorableInterface
{
    function getObject(mixed $primaryKeyValue): static;

    function find(mixed $primaryKeyValue): static;

    function save(): static;
}
```

Comment: If you are implementing the interface, your target class must implement declared methods on its own, have their implementation in the inheritance chain or in the traits implied. You cannot replace this implementation with the `__callStatic`

Answer (score 1):

Trait methods can be *"renamed"*: (actually it's an alias)

```php
use Queryable {
    find as MyFind;
}
```

[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Simple example:

```php
<?php

Trait myTrait
{
    public static function __callStatic ($method, $arguments)
    {
        $className = self::class;
        
        return (new $className ())->$method(...$arguments);
    }
    
    
    private function find()
    {
        echo "\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\n";
        return $this;
    }
}


interface MyInterface
{
    public function find();
}   


class Test Implements MyInterface
{
    Use myTrait {
        find as myFind;
    }
    
    public function find()
    {
        echo "\nxxxxxx\n";
    }
    
}


Test::myFind()->find();
```

Comment: This gives the following error:
Compile Error: An alias (queryFind) was defined for method find(), but this method does not exist

Comment: How is defined the find() method in your trait?

Comment: with a magic __callStatic() and phpdoc declaration like explained, ill add a new comment with the queryable trait

Comment: @NielsvanOijen - Please add your trait (the relevant parts) and the the same for the class you you're trying to implement it in to your question.

Comment: I've added the relevant trait, class and interface

Comment: I know your method works, but you haven't used the phpDoc declaration of the static function, which is what seems to be the problem as this allows the function to be called without being defined on the trait itself. phpStorm shows the correct data, yet php itself cant work with it

Comment: phpDoc is used only for documentation and to hint code editors. It is ignored by the PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want even more magic. The following code is absolutely not recommended due to `debug_backtrace` usage which i believe should not be met in the production code when everything goes as it should:

```php
class QueryBuilder{
    function find( mixed $arg ){
        $this->arg = $arg;
        print_r($this);
        return $this;
    }
}

interface Findable{
    static function find( mixed $args );
}
trait Queryable{

    public static function __callStaticWithMoreMagic(mixed $args){
        $method_name = debug_backtrace(2)[0]['function'];
        return (new QueryBuilder())->$method_name( $args );
    }

}
class SomeModel implements Findable{
    use Queryable {
        Queryable::__callStaticWithMoreMagic as find;
    }
}

print_r( SomeModel::find('something') );
```